# How can I create a toolbar button that applies a thousands-separated number style in OpenOffice.org Calc?

Tags: macros, openoffice-calc

In OpenOffice.org Calc I very often want to format numbers with a thousands separator.

How can I create a toolbar button to do this?

Via the menus, the appropriate format can be applied with Format -> Format Cells -> Number, and the number format is `#,##0`.

However I'd like to be able to add a button to the formatting toolbar to do this (via right-click on toolbar -> Customize Toolbar).  Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a pre-defined button for this - though there is "Number Format: Date", ..."Add Decimal", ..."Currency" etc.

Having done this a very long time ago in Excel, I suspect the solution would be to create a macro to do this.  If so, how do I do this?  Or is there a simpler alternative that I've overlooked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, creating a macro to do this was painless, here's how to do it in OpenOffice.org 3.2:

1. Select `Tools` -> `Macros` -> `Record Macro`
2. Select `Format` -> `Cells` -> then select required format and click OK.
3. Click `Stop Recording` and give the macro a suitable name.
4. (optional): Test the macro by selecting some cells and selecting `Tools` -> `Macros` -> `Run Macro` -> then select your macro.
5. Add the button by right-clicking on the toolbar, then `Customise Toolbar` -> `Add` -> `OpenOffice.org Macros` -> and select your macro.
6. Optionally you can assign an icon to your button via `Customise Toolbar` -> select your macro from the Commands list -> `Modify` -> `Change Icon`.